# Have Users Interact with MS Access Queries instead of Tables

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, ms-access

I am working on a project where I need to create a database to track the status of units throughout the production process.  My current blockade involves getting the users to interact with a DataGridView that is supplied from a Microsoft Access Query instead of a Microsoft Access Table.

What I want to do is create a query in Microsoft Access and have it link to the DataGridView so end users can interact with a query instead of the actual tables, while populating all parent tables.

I am not sure if what I am attempting to do is possible or advised.  This is the first time I have built a database in the professional world and want to make sure I am doing things properly.  I have also never built a C# application for business use and have very limited experience with the language itself.

I have tried creating the Query in Access and linking it to the application in the same way you would add a table from a data source.  That would allow me to view the data in the query...but it would display as a read-only and not allow for any data to be altered (the query builder in the TableAdapter Query Configuration Wizard indicated it was a read-only) .  I have tried adding all related table adapters to the TableAdapterManager and it still didn't help.

I apologize if this question sounds disjointed as I am trying to overcome one obstacle at a time and do not want to overload one question with multiple issues.  I can supply my ERD if it will make things easier and I have it normalized to at least 2NF.

Comment: When you test your query within an Access session, is it read-only there?

Comment: No it is not.  I have no issues within Access itself.  I only have issues when I try to interface it with the application.